# Correct grammatical number for English money

Tags: grammar, numbers

Which of the following is correct or better?
A) Here's £5.
B) Here are £5.
In case both should be correct, could you explain why?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Another related question, […but 20 dollars is 20 dollars](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279530/but-20-dollars-is-20-dollars),

Answer (score 0):

Before we close it as a duplicate, it's worth mentioning that the question might pertain to location/subject relation in the sentences. Contextual awareness is imporatnt.

- Here's £5

  Here is £5, as in, i'm placing either a £5 note or 5 pieces of £1, or a lot of other combinations. I don't see placing debt though, so that limits it. A less common usage of this sentence "type" is location indication. For example, someone pointing at a map, and says Here's £5. I find the latter highly unlikely.
- Here are £5

  Here are £5 is more commonly a location indicator(in this location, you can find [see above pound decomposition]), or the sentence is formed the other way around: I have £5 in my hand, here they are, and then i hand it over.

Here's £5 contains a shorthanded if, so it can be less formal and strict than the mentioned Here are £5 counterpart. I see strict parents granting money to their children via the latter sentence.

This is why, among plenty other reasons, these sentences are correct. Not relying on the obvious sentence composition rules being satisfied, either.

**Both sentences are grammatically valid, and correct.**

*Usage is contextual. See the comments of the OP for more clarification in context.*

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether an amount of money, or a number of coins, is being referred to.

If paying for something that costs £5 we would normally say here is £5. It is the amount that is important.

If somebody needs change for a slot machine, he may ask: "Do you have change for a fiver (five pound note)?". On handing him five pound coins we would say here are £5.

We would use "is £5" to specify an amount and "are £5" to specify a number of coins.